# Что не так с combinations_with_replacement?

Tags: python

Все знают замечательную библиотеку itertools. И на первый взгляд метод combinations_with_replacement должен делать то, что мне надо, а именно перебрать все возможные комбинации строки:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement


for i in combinations_with_replacement('xo', 3):
    print(''.join(i))
```

вывод будет
'
xxx
xxo
xoo
ooo
'
.
Но где же oxx, oox, xox... и т.д
Как получить реально ВСЕ возможные комбинации строки?

Comment: [Сочетания с повторениями](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5#%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8), [Размещения с повторениями](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5#%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот так вот:

```
import itertools

print(list(itertools.product('xo', repeat=3)))
```

Comment: print(len(list(itertools.product('qwertyuio', repeat=12)))) вызывает MemoryError. Как нибудь можно это обойти? Проще говоря я пытаюсь понять как мне написать брутфорс

Comment: Ответ нашел. Если что, гуглите 'python как избежать MemoryError'

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужны не перестановки, а всевозможные комбинации из символов `'x'` и `'o'`.

Всевозможные комбинации находятся с помощью Декартова произведения ([`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)).

```py
from itertools import product


for i in product('xo', repeat=3):
    print(''.join(i))
```

---

> print(len(list(itertools.product('qwertyuio', repeat=12)))) вызывает MemoryError. Как нибудь можно это обойти? Проще говоря я пытаюсь понять как мне написать брутфорс

При приведении генератора (а `itertools.product` возвращается именно генератор) к списку, выполняется высчитывание всех элементов генератора, чтобы их сохранить в список

Если вспомнить школьную математику, то количество комбинаций длины `n` `k`-элементного множества равно k<sup>n</sup>. Для вашего случая:

```py
In [1]: len('qwertyuio') ** 12
Out[1]: 282429536481
```

282429536481 комбинаций

Один кортеж с 12-ю символами (возвращаемые элементы генератора) занимает:

```py
In [1]: import sys

In [2]: "a"*12
Out[2]: 'aaaaaaaaaaaa'

In [3]: tuple(_)
Out[3]: ('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a')

In [4]: sys.getsizeof(_)
Out[4]: 136
```

136 байт

Итого, для хранения всех комбинаций понадобится `136 * 282429536481` = `38410416961416` байт (или, приблизительно, `38410.4` гигабайт) оперативной памяти +несущественные расходы на хранение списка и прочий мусор, но это мы считать не будем :)

Отсюда и ошибка `MemoryError`

Чтобы избежать ошибки, не надо пытаться хранить в памяти все значения, воспроизводимые генератором. Можно итерироваться сразу по генератору

```py
for i in product('qwertyuio', repeat=12):
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

[combinations_with_replacement](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) увеличивает (в разных вариантах) количество отдельных элементов до достижения нужной длины. Эта функция НЕ ПЕРЕСТАВЛЯЕТ элементы местами и не вставляетимеющиеся в другие места.

Результаты `oxx, oox, xox` не могут получиться в этой функции, т.к. в них имеется другая последовательность символов - `oх`